# Looking for Rule engine who can cycle through couple of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, rule-engine

Everything is in C#.

I have a an `array` of a certain class, which contain lots of fields and information.

I wanted to implement a Simple Rule Engine on that `array`, for example:
If `object1.name` is something and `object2.name` is something
and `Function(object1.value,object2.value)==True` then ....

I started using Windows Workflow Foundation and the problem I encountered is that
I give the rule engine a specific `object_type` to work on so I actually can't have the rule
checking 2 different objects.

For example, I tell the rule engine to work on `typeof(MY_CLASS)`.
Then the rule will look like this: "If `this.name` is something and (I can't call a different object!) ..."

I basically want the rule to run like this: "If `this[i].name` is something and `this[j].name` is something..."
So eventually all the couples in the array will be cycle through.

to clear things up, this is how I set the rule engine (WF):

public class My_Array{
string name,description... 
and lots of fields}

Data_Array = new My_Array[N];

RuleSet ruleSet = null;
RuleSetDialog ruleSetDialog = new RuleSetDialog(typeof(My_Array), null, ruleSet);

Now, a rule for example will be:
if this.name == "Name1" then this.description = "description1"

And this is how I execute the rule on ONE object:

```
RuleValidation validation = new RuleValidation(typeof(My_Array), null);
        RuleExecution execution = new RuleExecution(validation, Data_Array[0]);

        ruleSet.Execute(execution);
```

So the rule will only be applied on Data_Array[0]. I can do a loop to apply on all the Array but
its only being applied on one cell at a time.

I want to write rules that check more then one object at a time, for example, a rule like this:
if object1.name == something and object2.name == somethigelse then...

But the problem is the rule engine only work on one object at a time.

How can I do that? Apply a rule that will do what I want?

Comment: Check our IBMs iLog Rule Engine for .Net

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite understanding your question. And I am not allowed to comment yet.

You know  that the Interface to help you with sort among Arrays is IComparer , right?
 Here is a small example of sort, through arrays. Just tell me if you can addapt this some way, and how can I help you do it. Hopefully it will be clear enough.
  SO : back to basics :)

```
public class Human : IComparer<Human> 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Human first, Human second)
    {
        return  first .Name .ToCharArray().First().CompareTo(second.Name    .ToCharArray().First());

    }


}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComparer<Human> myCompare = new Human();

        Human[] myArray = new Human[3] { new Human() { Name = "Johny" }, new Human() { Name = "Alexander" }, new Human { Name = "Bobby" } };
        Array.Sort<Human>(myArray, myCompare);
        foreach (var item in myArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

    }
```

IComparer interface allows you to iterate to every two object in your array .

Comment: Of course , after your Sort is applied , you can do whatever with your array !

Comment: I'm afraid it not what I meant, I want to use the rule engine to call/compare/change more then 1 object in my array at once. I've edit my question so it'll be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed a simple rules engine for a project so I wrote my own (using Windows Workflow with a re-hosted workflow editor for the rule creators). It does not utilize any forward/backward chaining of rules like some of the other rule engines, just executes the rules from top to bottom against the desired .NET object. It's simple but it worked for what I needed. It was difficult enough to create so I decided to license it. Check http://www.enigmasupercomputing.com/RulesEngine for tutorials and demos and a 30-day trial.